# Connecting to OpenVPN in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, openvpn

I am wondering on how to connect to OpenVPN with VB.NET, I have attempted using the following code but then in the command line I get an error saying "Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: C:\Users\Minetro300\Documents\connection.ovpn
Use --help for more information.".

```
IO.File.WriteAllText((System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\vShield" & "\connection.ovpn"), My.Resources.OpenVPNCertificate)
IO.File.WriteAllText((System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\vShield" & "\connection.bat"), "openvpn " & System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\connection.ovpn")

Dim connect As System.Diagnostics.Process
connect = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
connect.StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\vShield" & "\connection.bat"
connect.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal

connect.Start()
connect.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to say that I don't know the reason for your error but here are some suggestions to write better code and then I realised that one of those suggestions would have solved your issue.  Look at the path of the file you specify in this line:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText((System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\vShield" & "\connection.ovpn", My.Resources.OpenVPNCertificate)
```

and now look at the path you specify for what I assume is supposed to be the same file in this line:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText((System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\vShield" & "\connection.bat"), "openvpn " & System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\connection.ovpn")
```

The path you specify to read the file from is not the same as the path you specify to write the file to, so is it any wonder that it can't read the file?

The advice I was going to give you about improving your code is to not use long expressions multiple times but, instead, use them once and assign the result to a variable, then reuse that variable.  If you had done that then you could not have messed up the path the second time.  So:

```
Dim ovpnFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "vShield\connection.ovpn"
```

You can now use that `ovpnFilePath` variable wherever you need that path and then you won't try to read from a different path to that which you wrote to.

That suggested code incorporates several other improvements too.  Firstly, importing namespaces that you use often and then not using them in your code.  As an example, `System` is already imported so you don't need to use `System.Environment` in code like you are.  What's worse, though, is that you use `System.Environment` in some places and just `Environment` in others, sometimes immediately adjacent.  That's bad coding.  If I see two different things in your code then I should be able to assume that they are different, not the same thing written two different ways for no good reason.  You should also be importing the `System.IO` namespace and not qualifying `File` with `IO` repeatedly.

Importing the `System.IO` namespace means that you can also use the `Path` class unqualified and you should be using that class to combine partial paths rather than using string concatenation.  Further to that, NEVER concatenate two literals together.  It's just silly and complicates your code for no good reason.

Looking more closely at your code, I see that you use two file paths multiple times and both files are in the same folder.  I would tend to do this for those paths:

```
Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "vShield")
Dim ovpnFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "connection.ovpn")
Dim batFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "connection.bat")
```

That will make your code much less complex and thus easier to read.  It will eliminate your current issue and make it less likely that you'll make more.

EDIT: Here is your original code written "properly":

```
Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "vShield")
Dim ovpnFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "connection.ovpn")
Dim batFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "connection.bat")

File.WriteAllText(ovpnFilePath, My.Resources.OpenVPNCertificate)
File.WriteAllText(batFilePath, String.Format("openvpn ""{0}""", ovpnFilePath))

Using connect As New Process(batFilePath)
    connect.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal    
    connect.Start()
    connect.WaitForExit()
End Using
```

As you can see, it's much easier to read for one thing.  It doesn't perform the same operations over and over so it nullifies the chance of making the mistake that caused you to post this question in the first place, i.e. use different paths when writing and reading a file.

It also gets rid of unnecessary qualifying namespaces.  `System` and `System.Diagnostics` are already imported by default, so no need to do anything with them.  This code does assume that you have also imported `System.IO`, which you can do at the file or the project level.

I've also used `String.Format` to create the commandline as it makes it cleaner to wrap the file path in double-quotes.  That's not strictly necessary in this case but it ensures that the commandline will still work if the file path has spaces in it, which is completely possible.

Finally, it correct disposes the `Process` object that you create by doing so with a `Using` block, which causes the object created at the `Using` statement to be disposed at the `End Using` statement.  You should always dispose any objects you create that support it.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but those 2 lines aren't the same file, one is a batch file that runs the openvpn command, and the second is the openvpn file that contains the certificate for the VPN... The program launches the batch file in result of an error, but when I manually open CMD it seems to work fine, but I don't know why it doesn't in batch, but thanks for trying to help! I appreciate it! ^_^

Comment: Good grief!  Read the code will you.  In the second line of code that I quoted you are writing to a batch file.  What are you writing to that batch file?  You're writing a commandline.  What does that commandline contain?  The path of the file that you wrote in the first line of code that I quoted, EXCEPT NOT!  Your commandline is telling openvpn what file to read but it's not providing the path of the file that you just wrote to.

Comment: I don't understand, what path of the file?

Comment: In the code you posted, the first line writes text to an OVPN file, right? The second line then writes a BAT file that contains a commandline instructing the OpenVPN application to open the file that you wrote in the first line, right? In that case, wouldn't the second line have to use the path of the file that you wrote in the first line? The problem is that you're not doing that.  In the first line, you specify the 'vShield' subfolder of your 'Documents' folder to write the file to. Look at the error message. It's telling you that it's failing to open a file that's NOT in that subfolder.

Comment: What @jmcilhinney is saying is that your parameter to open vpn is not the as the folder where you wrote the vpn certificate. You did not include the "vshield" folder

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you didn't keep building folder and file paths over and over then you couldn't build them correctly some times and incorrectly others. If you had built that path of that OVPN file once then you couldn't possibly use the wrong path on some occasion(s).

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a full rewrite of your code to be done the way I think it should, which addresses your original issue and a number of others with regards to code style.  I'm not sure that I wouldn't change it more - e.g. why set `WindowStyle` to its default value - but that's probably enough for now.

Comment: OH! I see what you mean now! I included the documents folder in the batch file but forgot to add “\vShield”. Thank you guys so much for your help and effort into helping me! Cheers!